# How to return substring from a linux command

Tags: linux, aix

I'm connecting to an exadata and want to get information about "ORACLE_HOME" variable inside them. So i'm using this command:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/cwd
```

this is the output:

```
2 oracle   oinstall          0 Jan 23 21:20 /proc/<pid>/cwd -> /u01/app/database/11.2.0/dbs/
```

i need the get the last part :

```
/u01/app/database/11.2.0  (i dont want the "/dbs/" there)
```

i will be using this command several times in different machines. So how can i get this substring from whole output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk and grep are good for these types of issues.

New:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/cwd | awk '{print ($NF) }' | sed 's#/dbs/##'
```

Old:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/cwd | awk '{print ($NF) }' | egrep -o '^.+[.0-9]'
```

Awk prints the last column of the input which is your ls command and then grep grabs the beginning of that string up the last occurrence of numbers and dots. This is a situational solution and perhaps not the best.

Comment: That's a good answer. But as you can see in the question, i dont want whole last column. So what's your solution about this? Also, what if i want to get, for example, the second column?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Actually, this worked in Linux but when i tried on AIX machine, it doesnt know "-o" parameter in "egrep". Is there something equal to that in AIX?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of `ls` is generally considered sub-optimal. I would use something more like this instead:

```
dirname $(readlink -f /proc/<pid>/cwd)
```